# Use previous row's calculated value to calculate current

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have this data frame

```
> df

# rn a b c  d  e  f
# 1  1 2 NA NA NA NA
# 2  5 8 NA 4  5  6 
# 3  8 5 4  2  3  2 
# 4  4 2 5  5  6  2
```

I am trying to create a new column that's based on these conditions:

- When columns `c` to `f` are all `NA`, then b
- When only `c` is `NA`, then return the smallest value in columns `b`, and `f` i.e. `min(b,f)` or `pmin`
- When no `NAs` exist in the row, return the least value in `b`, `e`, and `f + previous calculated value`

The desired output is:

```
> df

# rn a b c  d  e  f  g
# 1  1 2 NA NA NA NA 2
# 2  5 8 NA 4  5  6  6  ### ? [b=8, f=6; least value = 6] 
# 3  8 5 4  2  3  2  3  ### ? [b=5, e=3, 'f + previous calculated value' = 2+6=8; least value = 3]
# 4  4 2 5  5  6  2  2  ### ? [b=2, e=6, 'f + previous calculated value' = 2+3=5; least value = 2]
```

I have tried this but I have no idea how to access the previously calculated value (using `lag(g)` as a placeholder) :

```
df%>%
  mutate(g = case_when(
      is.na(c) & is.na(d) & is.na(e) & is.na(f) ~ b,
      is.na(c) & !is.na(d) & !is.na(e) & !is.na(f) ~ pmin(b,f),
      !is.na(c) & !is.na(d) & !is.na(e) & !is.na(f) ~  pmin(b,e, f+lag(g)),
      TRUE ~ NA)
   )
```

Maybe I am not thinking about this the right way. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am happy to be proven wrong, but I don't think this is possible in a single statement. You are using the results of your `case_when` to determine the `case_when` for the next row. Usually this sort of thing requires a loop, unless someone smarter than me can find a way to conceptualise this to run all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would say use a simple for-loop.
You cannot use `lag(g)` because you haven't built `g` column yet.

```
    res <- rep(0, nrow(df))
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      row <- df[i, ]
      if (is.na(row["c"]) && is.na(row["f"])) {
        res[i] <- row["b"]
      } else if (is.na(row["c"])) {
        res[i] <- min(row["b"], row["f"])
      } else if (!is.na(row["d"])) {
        res[i] <- min(row["b"], row["e"], row["f") + res[i-1])
      }
    }
    df$g <- res
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
#count the number of NAs in each row in columns c:f
DT[, nNAs := rowSums(is.na(.SD)), .SDcols=Xc:Xf]

#When columns c to f are all NA, then b
DT[DT[, .I[nNAs==ncol(.SD)], .SDcols=Xc:Xf], Xg := Xb]

#When only c is NA, then return the smallest value in columns b, and f i.e. min(b,f) or pmin
DT[DT[, .I[nNAs==1L & is.na(Xc)]], Xg := pmin(Xb, Xf)]

#When no NAs exist in the row, return the least value in b, e, and f + previous calculated value
DT[, sXg := shift(Xg)]
fpc <- NA_integer_
DT[nNAs==0L, Xg := {
        prev <- fcoalesce(fpc, sXg, 0L)
        fpc <- min(Xb, Xe, Xf + prev)
        fpc
    },
    1L:nrow(DT)]
```

output:

```
   rn Xa Xb Xc Xd Xe Xf nNAs Xg sXg
1:  1  1  2 NA NA NA NA    4  2  NA
2:  2  5  8 NA  4  5  6    1  6   2
3:  3  8  5  4  2  3  2    0  3   6
4:  4  4  2  5  5  6  2    0  2  NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("rn Xa Xb Xc  Xd  Xe  Xf
1  1 2 NA NA NA NA
2  5 8 NA 4  5  6 
3  8 5 4  2  3  2 
4  4 2 5  5  6  2")
```